# How to show my application all activity layout in landscape mode using landscape flag only once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

I have an application which contains multiples activity. I want to show all the activity layout in landscape mode for my applicaiton.

There is a common way to do that, which is declaring `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` flag for each activity in android  manifest file.

But this is weird when I have lots of activity and declaring that flag for all activity tag where I want to show all activity in landscape mode by default.

Is it possible or any way to declare that flag only once either manifest or activity to show all of my application activity layout in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can create BaseActivity and add layout type which you want

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
or
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Extend BaseActivity to all activities class.

Comment: It's not possible in my case.

Comment: why? what is the issue? which class you are extend in your all activities?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any a common way to do that, which is declaring `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` flag for each activity in android manifest file.

You have must apply `android:screenOrientation="landscape/landscape"` to each an every activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml file**

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    or
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```